# How to Restore Original File Association for .db Files on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, restore, file-association

I have accidentally changed the File Association for .db Files on my Windows 7 machine to WordPad. How can I restore the **original Windows** association for these files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, after much searching I found this [program](http://www.winhelponline.com/articles/231/1/An-Utility-to-Unassociate-File-Types-in-Windows-7-and-Vista.html) to delete the association.